# Ajuda com query para o problema criado?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, query

Preciso criar uma lista composta pelos campos Estágio Atual e Próximo Estágio ambos nomes de estágio vindos da mesma tabela.

Exemplo do resultado que busco:

[image: Tabela desejada]

Tabela Estágios (fornecedora do nome do estágio)

[image: Tabela fornecedora do nome do estágio]

O query busca na Tabela EstagiosCronologia (abaixo) os nomes dos estágios na tabela Estágios (acima):

[image: Tabela EstagiosCronologia]

Eu posso inclusive ter o mesmo ID para Atual e Próxima.

```
    SELECT e.Estagio AS Atual, 
    (SELECT e.Estagio FROM EstagiosCronologia ec 
    INNER JOIN Estagios e ON ec.ProximoEstagioId = e.EstagioId)  AS Proximo 
    FROM EstagiosCronologia ec 
    INNER JOIN Estagios e ON ec.EstagioAtualId = e.EstagioId
```

Esse query acima funciona para apenas um item - com a tabela EstagiosCronologia polulada me retorna um erro:

Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Como criar essa query?

Tabela EstagiosCronoligia

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EstagiosCronologia] (
        [CronologiaId]     VARCHAR (36) NOT NULL,
        [EstagioAtualId]   VARCHAR (36) NOT NULL,
        [ProximoEstagioId] VARCHAR (36) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CronologiaId] ASC),
        CONSTRAINT [FK_EstagiosCronologia_Estagios] FOREIGN KEY ([EstagioAtualId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Estagios] ([EstagioId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );
```

Tabela Estagios

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Estagios] (
    [EstagioId]   VARCHAR (36)    NOT NULL,
    [CursoId]     VARCHAR (36)    NOT NULL,
    [Estagio]     VARCHAR (50)    NOT NULL,
    [Duracao]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [ValorTabela] DECIMAL (10, 2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EstagioId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Estagios_Cursos] FOREIGN KEY ([CursoId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cursos] ([CursoId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Dados Cronologia

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EstagiosCronologia] ([CronologiaId], [EstagioAtualId], [ProximoEstagioId]) VALUES (N'7027a044-9530-446f-a60d-9971a206d452', N'508ccd5b-b177-4876-9b7c-987f64ada5ef', N'bb84bd20-4907-4a92-815f-44c08b24410a')
INSERT INTO [dbo].[EstagiosCronologia] ([CronologiaId], [EstagioAtualId], [ProximoEstagioId]) VALUES (N'dc72f06c-470b-4913-b480-4106e05831b4', N'bb84bd20-4907-4a92-815f-44c08b24410a', N'c86516bc-bae2-4edf-9c75-236cdc5fccd8')
```

Dados Estagios

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Estagios] ([EstagioId], [CursoId], [Estagio], [Duracao], [ValorTabela]) VALUES (N'508ccd5b-b177-4876-9b7c-987f64ada5ef', N'dc72f06c-470b-4913-b480-4106e05831b4', N'Teste', 40, CAST(1589.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Estagios] ([EstagioId], [CursoId], [Estagio], [Duracao], [ValorTabela]) VALUES (N'bb84bd20-4907-4a92-815f-44c08b24410a', N'dc72f06c-470b-4913-b480-4106e05831b4', N'Nursery Play', 40, CAST(1950.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Estagios] ([EstagioId], [CursoId], [Estagio], [Duracao], [ValorTabela]) VALUES (N'c86516bc-bae2-4edf-9c75-236cdc5fccd8', N'dc72f06c-470b-4913-b480-4106e05831b4', N'Teste 2', 40, CAST(1500.00 AS Decimal(10, 2)))
```

Comment: Cada estagio só pode ter um proximo?

Comment: não, cada estágio poderá ter mais que um próximo.

Comment: O erro ta acontecendo pq a subquery retorna mais de uma linha, basicamente vc ta tentenado colocar 2 ou mais registros dentro de um só, se cada estagio só pode ter um `Próximo` tem algo errado com a sua tabela  `EstagiosCronologia `

Comment: Consegue me passar os scripts de criação das tabelas com algum registro pra eu testar?

Comment: Ajuda assim - dessa forma?

Comment: adiciona na pergunta, se não vão apagar

Comment: Respondi, se não for isso que vc quer me avise

Comment: Desculpe Gabriel Oliveira, não vejo a resposta em nenhum lugar... sou novo no StackOverflow. Como faço pra ver a sua resposta?

Answer (score 0):

Cheguei na resposta.

```
SELECT e.Estagio AS Atual, (SELECT est.Estagio FROM EstagiosCronologia ecs INNER JOIN Estagios est ON ecs.ProximoEstagioId = est.EstagioId WHERE ecs.EstagioAtualId = ec.EstagioAtualId) As Proximo
FROM EstagiosCronologia ec 
INNER JOIN Estagios e ON ec.EstagioAtualId = e.EstagioId
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem lógica. Simples.

```
SELECT ec.*, ea.Estagio AS EstagioAtual, pe.Estagio As ProximoEstagio  
FROM EstagiosCronologia ec
JOIN Estagios ea ON ea.EstagioId = ec.EstagioAtualId 
JOIN Estagios pe ON pe.EstagioId = ec.ProximoEstagioId
```

Respondendo a minha própria dúvida.